# RealTime Data Update in Excel to Matlab

Tags: matlab, excel

I would like to know if someone has some experience in making Excel talk to Matlab in RealTime. I have data in Excel which are updated in realtime, but I want to see the same thing in Matlab.

I know we can use the DDE connection or even the Spreadsheet Link Ex but its never realtime meaning you need to excute a command before this gets done.

Do you have a way to do that automaticallY?